# iTunes 11 - how to "make iphone version"

Tags: itunes

I just got iTunes 11 and coincidentally just discovered that supposedly there was an option to "Create (or make?) iPhone version" in the older versions for movies and TV shows and such.

I would like to know how to do that iTunes 11.  Is this possible?  What other ways could I compress my downloaded TV shows and movies from the iTunes store such that they wouldn't take up so much space on my phone?

I want to compress the **SD** version which is typically about 590mb.

My goals:

1. that one episode would be around 150mb maximum
2. is possible, it would be even nicer to have them around 75mb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Click on the video.
2. In the menubar, go to File > Create New Version > Create iPod or iPhone Version.

Tip: 600 MB to 75 MB would be tremendous loss of quality. Even so, if you want a file 75 MB large, don’t use iTunes as you can’t modify conversion settings. Use a dedicated converter.

Comment: Funny how it was right there and I didn't notice it even though I looked under `File` _several_ times ha.  Thanks!  Except wait, the `create iPod or iPhone version` is grayed out.  Are these operations not allowed on content downloaded directly from the iTunes store?

Comment: Can you post a link to a full screen shot with the video selected and the menu open?

Comment: I looked at a few of mine.  And it does seem that this is grayed out for iTunes store videos.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Windows based version of iTunes you can hit ALT and access the File menu at the top, in the menu you can 'Create new version'.